# Traveling From Brussels to Amsterdam — Are Seat Reservations Mandatory for Eurail Pass 1st Class?

Tags: bookings, amsterdam, brussels

Trying to book seat reservations from Brussels to Amsterdam on an IC direct train —  I see no mandatory seat reservation required? We have Eurail Flexi-Saver passes, 1st class and I see no where to reserve seats, only to purchase tickets. Can anyone confirm that 1st class seat reservations are not needed? It is a Saturday afternoon train, departing at 15:52 and arriving at 17:42 . . .
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope you do not plan to travel soon as there is work on the track each Saturday in March 2017 ([according to my source](http://www.ns.nl/reisplanner-v2/index.shtml).)

Not only do you not have to make reservations for this train, it is impossible to make reservations. There is no system of reservations on this train, as indicated on that same source.

If you need to travel in March, there are alternative trains, but it takes several changes of trains.
Or it is possible to take the fast train but you need a reservation, it is rather expensive and there are (as far as I know) restrictions on numbers of passholders.
If you are flexible in which day you travel you might get around the works by going on a weekday. (But do double check for the day you actually want to travel.)